# sum of elements in list, when an element can take two different values

Tags: python, sum

I have a list of elements and want to get the sum of this list:
`a = [4, 5, "X", "X"]`.
But `X` can be 2 different values, 2 or 3. So there are 4 sums of this list:

```
sum1 = sum([4, 5, 2, 2]) = 13
sum2 = sum([4, 5, 2, 3]) = 14
sum3 = sum([4, 5, 3, 2]) = 14
sum4 = sum([4, 5, 3, 3]) = 15
```

Basically I want to get a tuple (or list) of all possible sums of the list, like:

```
sums = (13, 14, 14, 15)
```

For an input list with 0 `X`, I want to get a tuple with 1 element, for a tuple with 1 `X` a tuple of 2 elements, with 2 `X` tuple with 4 elements...with n `X` a tuple of 2^n elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `itertools.product` and a list comprehension

```
from itertools import product

a = [4, 5, "X", "X"]
r = a.count('X')
[sum(a[:len(a)-r] + [*i]) for i in product([2,3], repeat=r)]
```

Output

```
[13, 14, 14, 15]
```

---

Testing with more cases

```
#test cases
for n in range(5):
    a=[4,5, *['X']*n]  # [4,5] .... [4,5,'X','X','X','X']
    r = a.count('X')
    print([sum(a[:len(a)-r] + [*i]) for i in product([2,3], repeat=r)])
```

Output

```
[9]
[11, 12]
[13, 14, 14, 15]
[15, 16, 16, 17, 16, 17, 17, 18]
[17, 18, 18, 19, 18, 19, 19, 20, 18, 19, 19, 20, 19, 20, 20, 21]
```

Answer (score 2):

Similar to [Michael's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69178475/1639625), also using `itertools.product`, but with a dictionary mapping elements to possible values. This might be more flexible, allowing placeholders in all positions and different values for different placeholders, and also makes the code a bit simpler IMHO.

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> a = [4, 5, "X", "X"]
>>> vals = {"X": [2, 3]}
>>> [sum(p) for p in product(*[vals.get(x, [x]) for x in a])]
[13, 14, 14, 15]
```